# EOF warning : multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  int c, blank, tab, lines;
  int till = 0;
  blank = tab = lines = 0;
  while(till == 0)
    {
      c = getchar();
      switch(c)
    {
    case ' ' :
      blank++;
    case '\t' :
      tab++;
    case '\n' :
      lines++;
    case 'EOF' : /* warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar] */
      till = 1;
    }
    }
  printf("Blanks :%d Tab :%d Lines :%d\n", blank, tab, lines);
  return 0;
}
```

While I compile this code, it persists with this error:

> warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]

How can we use EOF in a `switch`?

Comment: Case EOF without cotes

Comment: 'EOF' is not a label, `switch` need a numeric label, `EOF` means -1 in most system.So change 'EOF' to -1 or just EOF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c, blank, tab, lines;
    int till = 0;
    blank = tab = lines = 0;
    while(till == 0)
    {
        c = getchar();
        switch(c)
        {
        case ' ' :
            blank++;
            break;
        case '\t' :
            tab++;
                    break;
        case '\n' :
            lines++;
            break;
        case EOF :
            till = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("Blanks :%d Tab :%d Lines :%d\n", blank, tab, lines);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You have one small mistake in the EOF case - you need to change:

```
case 'EOF':
```

to:

```
case EOF:
```

After that change the code should compile and run, but in order for it to run correctly you will need to add a `break;` line at the end of each case.

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
case 'EOF':
```

to:

```
case EOF:
```

And add `break;` after each case.

Answer (score 1):

You are using 'EOF' to represent End of file. The actual representation is EOF constant

```
case EOF : /* warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar] */
  till = 1;
}
```

its defined in stdio.h

Answer (score 1):

You could also do the following thing:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    switch (c)
    {
        /* case ' ', '\t', '\n' */
    }
}
```

`EOF` is a macro definition of type `int`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no character symbol `'EOF'`. In standard C library the `EOF` is a predefined constant. It's value varies between systems. So, in your case, you should change `EOF` comparison part to something like this:

```
...
case EOF:
        till = 1;
}
```